# What is the derivative of $\ln(4^x)$?

Tags: calculus

What is the derivative of $\ln(4^x)$  (which I believe is also equal to $x\ln4$)?

Is it $\dfrac{1}{x\ln4}$?

Comment: as you said, $ln(4^x)$ = $xln4$, so its derivative is simply $ln4$.

Comment: or did you mean $\left(\ln{4} \right)^x$ ?

Comment: [See this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/264) for an explanation of how to write math here.

Comment: Sorry, I have now edited the post to be more clear.

Comment: @Inceptio Thanks for the dfrac, I didn't know about that LOL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that for $a>0$, we have
$$\log(a^b) = b \log(a)$$
Also, note that
$$\dfrac{d}{dx}\left( cx\right) = c$$
I trust you can finish it from here.

Comment: The concept of ln, e, log always boggles me. I keep forgetting that they are constants and not scary math figures.

Answer (score 1):

The thing you are supposed to understand here is that constants don't do anything to derivatives -- they just factor out of the expression.
More precisely, we have for any function $f$ and a constant $c$ not depending on $x$ that
$$
\frac{d}{d x} c f(x) = c \frac{d}{d x} f(x)
$$
For example, since $\frac{d}{d x} (x^4) = 4x^3$, I can multiply by any constant and the derivative is just as straightforward:
$$
\frac{d}{d x} \left[ 2.33\pi^2 \cos (4) \right] x^4 
= \left[ 2.33\pi^2 \cos (4) \right] 4x^3
$$

This works since the $ 2.33\pi^2 \cos (4) $ is constant - it doesn't depend on $x$.

If you get this, you should be able to calculate derivatives like this easily.

Answer (score 1):

if your question is $ln(4^x)$ then its answer will be $\ ln4$ and if your question is $(\ln4)^x$ then use this formula
$$\dfrac {d}{dx}a^x=a^x\cdot\ln{a}$$
so
$$\dfrac {d}{dx}{(\ln4)}^x=(\ln4)^x\cdot\ln{(\ln4)}$$

Comment: I've given answer of both possibilities of question so please check carefully who downvote it

Comment: (+1). For providing both instances. The *down-voter* should definitely consider leaving a comment.

Comment: peoples are too fast to downvote without reading whole thing and don't want to write reason

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** : $\ln 4^x=y \implies x \ln 4=y$

Since $\ln4$ is a constant. The derivative is simply the constant, i.e $\ln 4$